# Problems with relative effect on Causal Package R

Tags: r, bayesian, causal-inference

I encounter the problem with the relative effect using the Causal Package on R.

```
# Model 3
ss3 <- list()
# Semi Local trend, weekly-seasonal
ss3 <- AddSemilocalLinearTrend(ss3, ts_dash_wk)
# Add weekly seasonal
ss3 <- AddSeasonal(ss3, ts_dash_wk, nseasons = 52)
model3 <- bsts(ts_dash_wk,
               state.specification = ss3,
               niter = 1500,
               burn = 500)
plot(model3, main = "Model 3")
plot(model3, "components")
Causal impact of dash and Covid-19 
pre.period <- as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2020-03-11"))
post.period <- as.Date(c("2020-03-11", "2020-12-31"))

# Obtain post period data
dat_dash_causal_post <- data_dash_wk %>% 
  filter(week >= as.Date("2020-03-11"))

# Use model 3 for causal impact
impact <- CausalImpact(bsts.model = model3,
                       post.period.response = dat_dash_causal_post$dash, alpha = 0.05)
plot(impact)

summary(impact)
```

[image]

The calculation of the relative effect is always wrong, the value is bigger than expected, and sometimes it goes negative although it should be positive. Please see my code and the report i receive. Would be much appreciated if you could help fix this issue.

Comment: If you think the internal calculations are wrong, you're better off taking that up with the package maintainer (though it looks like you may have already filed an [issue on their GitHub page](https://github.com/google/CausalImpact/issues/70)).  You can use `debugonce(CausalImpact)` and then run your analysis and it will allow you to step through all the calculations.  You may find your answer that way.